# Bluetooth headset profile not working with recent kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, audio, bluetooth

I have a Plantronics 590 bluetooth headset (the type probably does not matter, but I have no alternative to test).

Using the old 3.02 I was able to use this via pulseaudio.
With the current 3.11-amd64 kernel this does no longer work.

I am still able to pair and to connect to the headset, using HSP profile.
I get a "beep" on the headset to confirm connection.
Unfortunataly there is neither input nor output in pulseaudio
(with the old kernel `pavucontrol` shot the headset).

This is most likely related to the kernel or a module.

I am using debian testing (jessie).

- The current version of linux-image-amd64 is 3.13+56
- The current version of bluez is 4.101-4.1
- The current version of pulseaudio and pulseaudio-module-bluetooth is 5.0-2
- The current version of alsa-base is 1.0.25+3

I also tried debian stable (wheezy), 32bit, not working, but different:
I can connect the device, it appears in `pavucontrol` but sound does not work.

- The current version of linux-image-686-pae is 3.2+46
- The current version of bluez is 4.99-2
- The current version of pulseaudio and pulseaudio-module-bluetooth is 2.0-6.1
- The current version of alsa-base is 1.0.25+3~deb7u1

Comment: In my experience it's generally rare that old hardware that was working stops. It's more likely that something is not configured properly.

Comment: I got a hackisch workaroundisch solution, posted below. Maybe you can see what is configured wrong from that. If not I might be able to provide more information if you ask for it.

Comment: What does hciconfig say about the bluetooth device? Have you used bluetoothctl to check the pairing? Have you checked the log files /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog? What does the "rfkill list" tell you? Have you run btmon?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good solution because it is quite hackish.
But it is a work around. Maybe someone can find the real issue and provide a better solution. I suspect a bug somewhere.

I did the following (not sure if every step is essential):

1. Created the file ${HOME}/.config/pulse/client.conf with contents

   ```
   autospawn = no
   ```

   (if the file already exists you can probably just add the line)
2. Started pulseaudio manually from my session start script with

   ```
   pulseaudio -vvvv --log-time --log-target=file:${HOME}/var/log/pulseaudio.log &
   ```

   (you will need to adapt the log target, I suppose logging and verbose is not necessary, but it helps tracking down bugs)
3. Start `blueman-applet`, turn on device, do anything you need to do to pair, this was not a problem for me.
4. For some reason pulseaudio drops everything it knows about bluetooth at this point, so I do

   ```
   pactl load-module module-bluez4-discover
   pactl load-module module-bluez4-device
   ```
5. Start `pavucontrol` and notice the device appears.
6. Start `mumble` or Skype, or whatever. This should work now.